# Como deixar o programa aberto em python

Tags: python, python-3.x, lista, arquivo, sistema-de-arquivos

Fiz um programa que lê um arquivo mas ele lê e já fecha, como adicionar um 'Aperte S para sair' por exemplo e deixar o print na tela por mais tempo?
-abaixo esta o código

```
lista=open('item.txt','r')
for linha in lista
 itens=linha.split()
 print('Comprar', itens[0])
 linha=lista.readline()

lista.close()
```

Answer (score 2):

Para fazer um código rodar eternamente e você deside quando o código deve para use `while True:`

```py
while True:
    lista=open('item.txt','r')
    for linha in lista
        itens=linha.split()
        print('Comprar', itens[0])
        linha=lista.readline()


    resultado = input("Deseja encerrar, [y/n] ")
    if resultado.upper() == 'Y':
        lista.close()
        break
```

Desta forma o código continua sendo executado até que o usuário peça para sair, digitando y para sair.

Comment: Cara valeu implementei aqui, mas agora o código ta dando output só da primeira linha do arquivo agora :/
poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Tente remover o lista.close() para fora do if , deixando ele abaixo desta linha. ```linha=lista.readline() lista.close() ```

Answer (score 1):

Para fazer isso apenas basta um `input` vazio

```
# insira-o no final do seu código
input('Aperte qualquer tecla para fechar o programa...')
```

;)

Answer (score -1):

O parametro "r" é para leitura, cada linha que esta passando pelo FOR esta sobrescrevendo a primeira, tente alterar para "a" de "appending"

Antes:

```
lista=open('item.txt','r')
```

Depois:

```
lista=open('item.txt','a')
```

> 'r'   open for reading (default) 
>   'w'   open for writing, truncating theile first 
>   'x'   open for exclusive creation, failing if the file already exists if it exists 
>   'a'   open for writing, appending to the end of the file
>   'b'   binary mode 't'     text mode (default) 
>   '+'   open a disk file for updating (reading and writing)

Fonte: [Documentação](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Comment: Não, pois vc esta usando o FOR para percorrer cada linha, caso não tivesse poderia ler todo o documento com o .readlines() mas lhe retornaria uma lista.